# pasting bug inkscape

Tags: inkscape

Trying to copy the (ii)
[image: image 1]

pasting here yields
[image]

Why does the pasted image look so strange?

Comment: sorry idk why the images aren't working properly

Comment: Hi. Were these documents made in Inkscape or some other software? Are the elements you are trying to copy editable text or outlines? Looks a bit like some kind of font substitution but that's only a guess. It's really hard to answer this without access to the SVG files

Comment: Assuming the text is actual editable text, try selecting the text objects and do *Path > Object to Path*, now try copying and pasting.

Comment: @BillyKerr  these are made in graffle

Comment: @BillyKerr  Here is the eps  https://drive.google.com/file/d/186O-PA788Bdq2QV8OEyLQ2t0_tZ3WxVr/view?usp=sharing     https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZOqqDcYHI7mc-lStjpIzp03upN4sOznK/view?usp=sharing    
I just need to copy the label in anyway as image is fine as well

Comment: I've added an answer now.

Answer (score 1):

Cannot prove it, but seems like Inkscape is trying (see NOTE1) play fair. I mean one cannot edit text objects which use fonts that are not installed to one's computer, but they are rendered OK with the embedded (=included in the EPS file) font subset.

The (ii) -item is a text object. Programs like Adobe Acrobat Pro render your EPS, but no text edits are possible except by using a substituted font. Illustrator (a legacy version) substituted all with Arial, it gave only this warning:

[image]

Serif Affinity Publisher was generous. It converted your (ii) to paths. I could export them as SVG and open the result in Inkscape. The result looked OK, except it was an incredible messy multilevel group. By applying Extension > Arrange > Deep Ungroup it finally became to this:

[image]

The i-letters are combined paths.

This single (ii) is easiest to fix by rewriting it, but I guess that's not a pleasant option if there are numerous other objects with the same problem.  In this case:

a) Try deep ungroup and then try to convert the (ii) to path.

b) Get the mentioned fonts. Inkscape may then open the file OK without preventing text edits.

c) Save the graph in the original program as PDF and open it in Inkscape  with Poppler-Cairo import. That import method converts texts to paths. You may need to perform Deep Ungroup to dig the interesting items out.

No guarantee. I have Inkscape Portable which is limited when compared to the installed version. It didn't open your EPS.

BTW. I have not installed Ghostscript nor know is it required.

NOTE1: there can well be a bug. There's another answer where user Billy Kerr says that his Inkscape gave the (ii) only as a bitmap. The EPS import functionality probably is still under construction and varies from build to build.

Comment: Interesting, I couldn't get a vector object either using Inkscape or Illustrator, not even Arial. But then again,  I don't seem to have the font installed. Do you know what it is?

Comment: I think the font might be Latin Modern Roman Italic, which seems to be freely available - although the OP will need to check the license. Link here: https://www.1001fonts.com/latin-modern-roman-font.html

Comment: @BillyKerr I inserted Illustrator's font notification to the answer. The shown font names occur also in the infoline  font name box when one selects a text object in Illustrator and such fonts seem to be available in web.

Comment: Yeah, Computer Modern Roman Italic, basically the one I linked to is a rip-off of the same font.

Comment: @BillyKerr Maybe you can find if Inkscape has some not so well visible options how to cope with missing fonts. The questioner succeeded to render his EPS ok, the problems started with edits. You got a bitmap straight away.

Comment: yeah it's a bit weird. Have to say I don't really know what's going on with that. Note also that I got the same result with Illustrator. I'm all out of ideas unfortunately.

Comment: @BillyKerr you can use acrobat to turn the text into outlines. Anyway the problem is name mangling. Even if you had the font installed it wouldn't do it automatically since the name has been abbreviated by the EPS generator. This is rare but some software like, sigh, matlab does this. It is entirely unnecessary just adds 3 minutes to import but makes beginners EXTRE;MELY frustrated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a bug in Inkscape.  I downloaded the EPS you shared, and this is what I found inside it.

The label is a low resolution raster image, which is inside a clipping mask, and it's also a clone of the image. Releasing the clip doesn't appear to work - just turns black, but releasing the clone works, however the raster image is such poor quality it's not really worth using.  It's just a low resolution greyscale image 184px x 163px.

Here it is:

[image]

The image is also a raster image when I checked by opening the EPS using Adobe Illustrator.

I can copy and paste the label into another document from Inkscape, and can't reproduce the problem you show in your screen shot.

Personally, I would just find a suitable italic font and retype it. It looks very similar to [Latin Modern Roman Italic](https://www.1001fonts.com/latin-modern-roman-font.html) - which is free to use according to the licence.

The problem has probably been caused by the software that was used to generate the EPS. If you want to fix this, perhaps seek support from the developers of that software.

**Edit**, after seeing user287001's answer, a missing font may be the problem. I don't know if the software you mentioned is capable of converting text to outlines, but that may be one possible fix.

Comment: It may not be a bug by Inkscape standards but it's incredibly annoying. Is there a way to just copy so it's one eps image on top of another?

Comment: @HaoS Not as far as I'm aware. Remember that Inkscape is an SVG editor, so EPS files (which are not a native format for Inkscape) have to be converted internally to objects which Inkscape can edit. This is one part of the problem, but the other part of the problem here is likely the missing font (or corrupted font name - see joojaa's comment above). Just retype the letters. It's really the simplest solution.

Comment: not always an option because sometimes the file is partially generated in graffle and partially in inkscape.  Although slight differences in font aren't gonna be that big of a deal.